# Magnetic moment of superconductors

Tags: superconductivity, magnetic-moment

How would a superconductor's magnetic moment be affected when it is placed in an increasing magnetic field?

I know that as the magnetic field gets stronger, fluxons begin to penetrate into the superconductor, but would this reduce the overall magnetic moment of the superconductor?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer, but check for Knight shift in superconductors on literature, you may find something of interest for you.